# GAE & GCSQL extremely slow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am running the phpMyAdmin app on my `Google App Engine` project.

My SQL properties:
[image: Google Cloud SQL properties]

Here is the `Google App Engine` instance summary:
[image]

This might be of relevance?
[image: Instance console]

I am at a complete loss, why it takes 5 seconds to get the page loaded on average. Is GAE even a feasible option for someone trying to run a website. I know I'm using the shared CPU but I am the only one currently (trying to) using it.

Comment: The response time is *primarily* dictated by the app code.

Comment: @DanCornilescu: I am deploying the `phpMyAdmin` code that runs extremely fast on my loca machine. Is it a known issue that it takes long to load?

Comment: Not a good idea to compare w/ local machine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41390857/4495081

Comment: Did you try to "heat up" your app? I mean, did you try to run some requests to make sure your app stabilizes, and then start monitoring the latency?

Comment: I haven't really done that. What I've done is work with `phpMyAdmin` in a normal fashion but that lasted about 5 minutes before I got impatient.