# Google app engine nodejs local development

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Is there a way to run my nodejs application locally so that I can simulate my application running in production App Engine without deploying it? For some reason my app behaves differently in the Google App Engine compared to my localhost.

I am getting tired of deploying my application to Google App Engine every time I make a change just to see if there's a bug.

Comment: Could you detail what are the differences that you notice?

Answer (score 0):

You'll never get *exactly* the same behaviour on your local system and on the real GAE infrastructure. For once simply because the infrastructure on which you're running is different: OS, hardware and network performance/capabilities, performance/capabilities of the actual vs SDK-simulated google APIs and services your app may be using, timing, etc.

A few examples (they're from the standard env GAE, it's true, but it's fundamentally the same idea):

- [FetchOptions withLimit() does not reduce query execution time (Google App Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299070/fetchoptions-withlimit-does-not-reduce-query-execution-time-google-app-engine)
- [Datastore fetch VS fetch(keys_only=True) then get_multi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271503/datastore-fetch-vs-fetchkeys-only-true-then-get-multi)
- [Why does Google Cloud SQL (using JDBC) take longer to insert records from Google App Engine than from my personal computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389295/why-does-google-cloud-sql-using-jdbc-take-longer-to-insert-records-from-google/41390857#41390857)
- [Ndb strong consistency and frequent writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896363/ndb-strong-consistency-and-frequent-writes/44907543#44907543)

You should investigate the differences - you're more than welcome to ask questions about each one of them right here, on SO.

In general you'll find the differences falling in 2 categories:

- plain performance differences, expected, but they may uncover actual problems in your code: race conditions, wrong timing assumptions, etc
- functional differences - to find general areas where you want to perform testing on GAE rather than locally.

  For example I learned (the hard way) that the SDK datastore emulator doesn't emulate the contention logic from the real datastore - while locally my app was running fine, on GAE it was crawling miserably due to contention, I had to re-write a good portion of the logic to address it. See [Contention problems in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927068/contention-problems-in-google-app-engine)