# FetchOptions withLimit() does not reduce query execution time (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

## Problem

Running a datastore query with or without *FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(100)* takes the same execution time! Why is that? Isn't the limit method intended to reduce the time to retrieve results!?

### Test setup

I am locally testing the execution time of some datastore queries with Google's App Engine. I am using the Google Cloud SDK Standard Environment with the App Engine SDK 1.9.59.

For the test, I created an example entity with 5 indexed properties and 5 unindexed properties. I filled the datastore with 50.000 entries of a test entity. I run the following method to retrieve 100 of this entities by utilizing the *withLimit()* method.

```java
public List<Long> getTestIds() {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(100);
    Query q = new Query("test_kind").setKeysOnly();
    for (Entity entity : datastore.prepare(q).asIterable(fetchOptions)) {
        ids.add(entity.getKey().getId());
    }
    return ids;
}
```

I measure the time before and after calling this method:

```java
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int size = getTestIds().size();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.info("time: " + (end - start) + " results: " + size);
```

I log the execution time and the number of returned results.

### Results

When I do not use the *withLimit()* FetchOptions for the query, I get the expected **50.000 results** in about **1740 ms**. Nothing surprising here.

If I run the code as displayed above and use *withLimit(100)* I get the expected **100 results**. However, the query runs about the same **1740 ms**!

I tested with different numbers of datastore entries and different limits. Every time the queries with or without *withLimit(100)* took the same time.

### Question

Why is the query still fetching all entities? I am sure the query is not supposed to get all entities even though the limit is set to 100 right? What am I missing? Is there some datastore configuration for that? After testing and searching the web for 4 days I still can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, you shouldn't expect meaningful results from datastore performance tests performed locally, using either the development server or the datastore emulator - they're just emulators, they don't have the same performance (or even the 100% equivalent functionality) as the real datastore.

See for example [Datastore fetch VS fetch(keys_only=True) then get_multi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271503/datastore-fetch-vs-fetchkeys-only-true-then-get-multi) (including comments)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I run some tests with the datastore in the cloud. There the withLimit() function does actually limit the execution time of the datastore query. So it actually works as expected and I will keep testing in the cloud. Yet, still pretty inconvenient that the local datastore performs so differently.