# Google App Engine php 5.5, high latency, slow response. How to fix it?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, nginx, optimization, low-latency

I migrated my web app from another service to GAE.
Problem is that **latency go from 14 to 21 seconds**, **not only at start**.
Here some example:
[Latency app engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu0dR.png)
[image]

Is there any workaround for any better performance?
Before this, the application was on Apache, and all work was good.
On GAE I have **NGINX**
**Memcache is already setted**, but I cannot solve this problem.

Hope someone can suggest some tip!
Thanks.

Comment: What machine characteristics were you using on apache and what instance class you have now? Also take a look at this answer, some of the points *might* be applicable to the comparison you're doing as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389295/why-does-google-cloud-sql-using-jdbc-take-longer-to-insert-records-from-google/41390857#41390857

Comment: Thanks man! 
I solved, was a problem with my php code.
Better code ---> better performance