# cURL is slow on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

I'm hosting a small `php` based application on Google App Engine and cURL is taking time. Earlier, when I was hosting on a dedicated server stack (with apache),  response time used to be less than 2 seconds. But when I moved to Google App Engine, it's slow, around 8-9 seconds.

I'd to enable `curl lite` with a new `php.ini` file to got it to work with cURL in the first place.

What do you suppose might be slowing it down?

Comment: Potentially of interest (but consider your apache server instead of the local machine in the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389295/why-does-google-cloud-sql-using-jdbc-take-longer-to-insert-records-from-google/41390857#41390857

Comment: I was on `aws`, but then it's just a small personal app and I wanted to go free and with a domain, so that's why I moved.

Comment: What kind of GAE are you using?, Maybe the deployed region you're using is far away/is saturated with applications or is restricted.