# Google App Engine terminates because of insufficient memory

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created a web app on google app engine manipulating images. The app works perfectly fine locally and it is very responsive too. But on app engine it is slow and it often crashes with the following error.

```
While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

Reading around I have seen some suggestions about upgrading the instance, I have done so, I have upgraded `instance_class: F2`, but still no success. My local laptop can do a much better job. Why? How can I solve this ? please help.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41390857/4495081 for comparing GAE with local machines. How much memory does your laptop have? (note MB vs GB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the F2 instance class has relatively small resource allocation compared to a modern laptop.

You may have to increase that even further, thought that will come with increased costs.

You can check the resource allocation for each instance class [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes)