# Why is my Google App Engine instance initialization latency so high (50s)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-app-engine, keras, google-cloud-platform

The following global imports seem to increase the initialization latency from 4s to ~ 50s:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import load_model
```

This only occurs on the live app engine and not the development preview, which runs main.py almost instantaneously.

I'm on `keras==2.2.4` and `tensorflow==1.14.0`. I checked the logs and the error reporting, and there don't seem to be any errors.

One thing I noticed is in the logs it prints out `Using Tensorflow Backend` about 8 times, whereas the development preview only says it once. Is it re-importing keras on loop?

I am running on `Flask==1.1.2` and `instance class F4_1G`.

[Latency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg6rh.png)

[There's also a 30 second delay between tensorflow setup processes?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6UNz.png)

---

Edit #1:

The [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8cbn.png) still show multiple `Using Tensorflow Backend` despite only [intializing a single instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SypcU.png). Also, I'm not sure why the memory is at 1.1GB. I don't initialize anything globally besides a few strings.

---

Edit #2:

`Using Tensorflow Backend` is printed out 8 times because there are 8 `gunicorn` workers, I think. I can reduce the workers by scaling back my instance type to one smaller than `F4_1G`, but then the logs show that I've `Exceeded soft memory limit` and that I should upgrade my instance type. Not sure why the initialization takes so much memory (1.1 GB).

Comment: `Using Tensorflow Backend` is printed only once per process start. Does app engine start multiple python instances?

Comment: I have automatic scaling enabled, so I suppose it might start multiple instances. I'm not sure how I can monitor the count though.

Comment: You can use this `gcloud app instances list` to check how many instances are up, here is the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/list) for it. This would explain the reason you have so many calls to TensorFlow, but not the latency necessarily though.

Comment: The speed on your local machine may be significantly higher than on GAE, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41390857/4495081. You may want to tweak the autoscaling parameters to account for a longer init time so that it doesn't spawn too many instances (which can be expensive).

Comment: I'm not using my local machine to test; rather, I'm using the GAE "web preview" which is run on the Cloud Shell VM, I think. Still, the Cloud Shell VM takes 1-2 seconds to import the Keras/TF library, whereas GAE takes 50 seconds, on average. I feel like that's miles longer than it should take.

Comment: What `entrypoint` are you using? Are you starting `gunicorn` with multiple workers or threads? You might want to experiment with it's `--preload` option.

Comment: I've not specified an entrypoint, so it defaults to gunicorn w/ the # of workers according to my instance type, which is F4_1G (8 workers). I guess that's why it was printing out `Using Tensorflow Backend` 8 times